# The links in my footer are stacked on top of each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, footer

I would like to make my links follow each other, but instead they're stacking up.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

See? In the left corner.

```css
footer {
  .footer {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    display: block;
  }
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p class="footer text-left">
    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    <a href="#">GitHub</a>
    <a href="#">OpenCollective</a>
  </p>
  <p class="footer text-right">Skott.io &copy; 2020</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: remove position:absolute; on a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `a` links are stacked because it's aligned on absolute position.
Remove `position: absolute` on `a` tag style and it will work with no issues.

```css
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

footer .footer {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: block;
}

footer a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<footer>
  <p class="footer float-left">
    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    <a href="#">GitHub</a>
    <a href="#">OpenCollective</a>
  </p>
  <p class="footer float-right">Skott.io &copy; 2020</p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between; /* to spread the content from left to right */
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0
}

.footer {
  font-family:'Ubuntu Mono',monospace;
  font-size:8pt;
  font-weight:400;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:-0.1px;
  margin:0 5px;
  display:block;
}

footer a {
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  margin-right: 5px; /* you can change as per your requirement */
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p class="footer text-left">
    <a href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a href="#">Twitter</a>
    <a href="#">GitHub</a>
    <a href="#">OpenCollective</a>
  </p>
  <p class="footer text-right">Skott.io &copy; 2020</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer, if issue is solved.

Comment: I think you've accepted some other answer other than mine.

Comment: yes, your solution ended up by not working, couldnt edit some spaces between links

Comment: I added margin-right to a tag in css. You can check once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223715/discussion-between-rafee-shaik-and-andrzej-jesztar).